# How to encode a list in python 2.7.8 ?

Tags: python-2.7, list, gis, encode, arcpy

I try to find a duplicate row value in field named "KOD" and then insert those values into "list2" and then print it. The field contain values with numbers and charecters not in English language(right to left language).

I using this code:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"G:\desktop\Project\lyr\aaa.shp"
list1 = []
list2 = []
counter = print list2
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, "KOD") as cursor:name
    for row in cursor:
        list1.append(row)
        if list1.count(row) >= 2 :
            list2.append(row)
            counter = counter +1
print counter
print list2
```

this is the result:

```
>>> 
[]
6
[[u'\u05d3/640'], [u'69/100/02/10'], [u'\u05d3/640'], [u'35/100/02/10'], [u'1/195/03/10'], [u'35/100/02/10']]
>>>
```

i get 6 duplicated values- it's true, but i get also a strange strings names.

How can i decode those strings?

I already asked it in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228104/print-a-duplicate-field-list-values-using-arcpy , but the moderator decided that this question suitable to stackoverflow.

Comment: Those string are unicode escape sequences. You can simply print them to display them. What are you trying to do?

Comment: i trying to print "list2".

Comment: i inserted a print command- i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: how can i print it?

Comment: `import itertools; print(' '.join(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list2))))`

Comment: You can answer it yourself :-)

Comment: thanks man, maybe python will bring the peace ;-) ...